# How to initialize bias with a pre-defined vector in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, keras-layer, initializer

How can I initialize bias with a pre-defined vector (no constant or random)? For example, I would like to spread up the vector in the range **[-1, 1]**. Something likee this:
 `tf.linspace(-1, 1 , shape,  name="linspace")`

what I have done so far, that it is not working,  is:

```
def b_init(shape):
    return tf.keras.initializers.Constant(tf.linspace(-1, 1 , shape,  name="linspace"))
```

I am looking for something I can call in the same way that the predefined classes, for example:

```
b_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal(seed=initialization_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the guide on the keras documentation: [Creating custom initializers](https://keras.io/api/layers/initializers/#creating-custom-initializers).

> #### Simple callables
>
> You can pass a custom callable as initializer. It must take the
> arguments shape (shape of the variable to initialize) and dtype (dtype
> of generated values):
>
> ```
> def my_init(shape, dtype=None):
>     return tf.random.normal(shape, dtype=dtype)
>
> layer = Dense(64, kernel_initializer=my_init)
> ```

In your case, you can simply use the following function:

```
def linspace_init(shape, dtype=None):
    return tf.linspace(-1, 1, shape, dtype=dtype)
```

And use it as an initializer in your layers.

```
layer = Dense(64, kernel_initializer=linspace_init)
```

If you absolutely want to have an object rather than a simple function, you just have to subclass the `Initializer` class:

```
class LinSpace(tf.keras.initializers.Initializer):

    def __call__(self, shape, dtype=None)`:
      return return tf.linspace(-1, 1, shape, dtype=dtype)
```